# Dynamically Handle Multiple Buttons in Views | Pycord, Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I'm switching from Novus to Pycord and attempting to translate the buttons functionality. I'm trying to take a list and add buttons 1-n for the length of the list then get the custom_id of whatever button was selected. After it is selected I want to **continue the command and use the custom_id throughout the rest of the command**. So far this is what I have:

```py
@bot.slash_command(name='bombs', description='Returns bombs to destroy base and airfield.')
async def bomb(ctx):
    await ctx.interaction.response.defer()
    countries = ["America", "Britain", "China", "France", "Germany", "Italy", "Japan", "Russia", "Sweden"]

    view = DefaultView()
    for number in list(range(1, len(countries) + 1)):
        view.add_item(DefaultButton(label=str(number), custom_id=str(number)))
    country_choice_message = await ctx.interaction.followup.send("Select a country to view bombs from:", view=view)

    timed_out_ = await view.wait()
    if timed_out_:
        view.disable_all_items()
        view.stop()
        await country_choice_message.edit(view=view)
        await ctx.interaction.followup.send("Timed out.", ephemeral=True)
        return

    # country_number = button_custom_id
    # do other stuff with country_number...


class DefaultButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self, custom_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.custom_id = custom_id


class DefaultView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    async def callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        self.disable_all_items()
        self.stop()
        await interaction.response.defer()
        await interaction.edit_original_message(view=self)
```

It doesn't hit the view callback at all and just says "This interaction failed." If I add a callback to the `DefaultButton()` class the interaction doesn't fail anymore but still doesn't return to the rest of the command and just quits instead at the end of the callback:

```py
class DefaultButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self, custom_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.custom_id = custom_id

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        self.custom_id = interaction.custom_id
        await interaction.response.defer()
        return
```

The timeout works, however, and successfully disables all the view items after the default (I think 180 seconds?) wait time has expired.

Edit: The only other post I could find related to this is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71209178/14267429). It doesn't solve my issue of not knowing how many buttons I might have. If I did I could just hard code all the button callbacks and call it a day.

Edit: Solved with @Ice Wolfy's answer below. [Full code](https://mystb.in/StageFlashAlbany.ruby).

Comment: Would an entire view have its own callback? Or doesn't every separate button have a callback?

Comment: I added a callback to the `DefaultView()` class but it never got hit.

Comment: I don't think view callbacks get called though, that's the thing. Callbacks for buttons get called for sure. Are you trying to associate that callback with every button?

Comment: Right if you saw what I added towards the bottom that's what I concluded as well. Just not sure why I can't continue with the command after the button callback.

Comment: Yes, that callback is associated with every button. Like I said in the post my issue is that after the `return` the command just quits. Even if I don't include `return` it quits after the last line in the button callback anyway and doesn't continue with the rest of the command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The view will not stop waiting until the timeout ends or you stop the view with `View.stop()`. To do this in the callback for a button use `self.view.stop()`.
[Docs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=view#discord.ui.View.stop)

You should also override the `on_timeout` function in the subclasses view instead of using the `timed_out_` variable. This is the way pycord intends and is more OOP friendly.
[Docs](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=view#discord.ui.View.on_timeout)